# PHP Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this

Tags: php

I get this error from my script:

```
[Fri Apr 23 10:57:42 2010] [error] [client 10.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot re-assign $this in C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Apache2.2\\htdocs\\abp\\fol\\test.php on line 27, referer: http://abp.bhc.com/fol/
```

Here is the code which produces the error:

```
<?php
$voiceboxes = array(
    '141133'    => array(
        'title' => 'Title',
        '1'     => array(
            'Title' => 'Title2',
            'Link'  => 'http://...',
        ),
        '12'    => array(
            'Title' => 'Title3',
            'Link'  => 'http://...',
        )
    ),
    '1070453'   => array(
        'title' => 'Title4',
        '1'     => array(
            'Title' => 'Title5',
            'Link'  => 'http://...',
        )
    )
);
$last = 0;
//$this = 0;
echo "<ol>\n";
foreach ($voiceboxes as $key => $value) {
    $last = 0;
    $this = null; //Error is thrown here, Line 27
    //$voiceboxes[$key]['title']
    echo "<ol>\n";
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($key2 == 'title') {
            echo "<li>$value2</li>\n";
        } else {
            $this = (int) $key2;
            if ($this == $last + 1) {
                echo '<li>';
            } else { '<li value="' . $key2 . '">';}
            $last = $key2;
            echo $voiceboxes[$key][$key2]['Title'] . "<br/>" . $voiceboxes[$key][$key2]['Link'] . '</li>' . "\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</ol>\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to rename $this to something else.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$this` is a predefined variable in PHP.

Here's the reference in the PHP manual: [Classes and Objects: The Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). It describes how, inside a method, $this points to "this object" that is being operated upon. It is still reserved outside a method, though.

Change the identifier to another word.

Answer (score 11):

`$this` is a special variable in php.  If this code is taking place inside a class, `$this` is a reference to the object the method is being invoked on.  You cannot assign a new value to `$this` inside of a class.  It is a limitation of PHP that you also cannot assign to a variable named `$this` outside of a class, where it would otherwise be valid to do so.

I believe this was valid in PHP4, but as of PHP5 You'll have to choose a new variable name.

Comment: Well, it isn't in a class, but thanks anyway, and also to the one above. He gets the check, however, because it apparently doesn't work outside a class either.

Comment: No, as I said, it is a limitation of PHP.  You cannot assign to `$this` in any context, inside of our outside of a class method.

Comment: Well, that came later. The other guy got it right the first time ;-) Thanks, anyway

Comment: Actually, you didn't add it till after I left the comment and refreshed the page.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of why you might have it in your code i.e. valid in PHP4

Answer (score 5):

You can reassign `$this` value by variable variable

```
$name = 'this';
$$name = 'stack';
echo $this;
// this will result stack
```

Comment: This hack is hardly an answer to the question!

Comment: Didn't work in the class constructor :/. But it is totally in PHP's spirit - hack the hacks.+

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really a PHP expert, but i think `$this` is referring to the current object, so if you set `this` to `null`, you try to set the current object to nothing, wich can not work.