# Change the value of $this in PHP

Tags: php

I'm developing a program that has to do with Question asking, so imagine there's the Question class. If I wanted to refer to a static function in Question which creates a Question item could I assign this object to $this variable?

**In a more general perspective**

Is it possible to change the value of $this variable of a class? If yes, how can you do that? Otherwise why can't I hook $this to another object of same class?

Comment: Can you show in terms of code what you are trying and what you need ??

Comment: Start with http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pseudo-variable *$this* is a reference to the calling object. Trying to re-assign it will generate a fatal error.

---

PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Similar question: [PHP Fatal error: Cannot re-assign $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699587/php-fatal-error-cannot-re-assign-this)

Answer (score 1):

So, I think you are a little foggy on what `$this` is for.  It is simply a way to refer to the instance of the class that is being utilized.  This reference only occurs within the class.

For example:

```
class Question
{
    function __construct($question, $correctAnswer)
    {
        $this->question = $question;
        $this->correctAnswer = $correctAnswer;
    }

    function answerQuestion($answer)
    {
        if ($answer == $this->correctAnswer) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice to determine if the answer is correct we compare the provided answer against:

```
$this->correctAnswer
```

If we create two different questions:

```
$questionOne = new Question("Who is the founder of Microsoft?", "Bill Gates");
$questionTwo = new Question("Who is the CEO of Apple, Inc?", "Tim Cook");
```

And provide the same answer, we get different results:

```
$isCorrect = $questionOne->answerQuestion("Tim Cook"); // FALSE
$isCorrect = $questionTwo->answerQuestion("Tim Cook"); // TRUE
```

This is because `$this` refers to the instance being used.

So, within the class, you use `$this`.
Outside the class, you use the object name.  In this case: `$questionOne` or `$questionTwo`

I hope that helps clear things up.